# Enumerate test data for parallel xUnit tests

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, parallel-processing, xunit

I have an xUnit test class with a single test method. I’ve been using this to load a file containing test descriptions but I want to run these in parallel.

Knowing that xUnit test classes always run their test methods in series, I thought I could define some subclasses which would then inherit the test and run in parallel. This worked.

The problem is that the test data is loaded, apparently, uniquely for each test class. I’m trying to make this thread safe so that I can provide unique items to each test method:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Xunit.Abstractions;
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(MaxParallelThreads = 10)]
namespace MultiTest;
public class Data
{
    public static readonly ConcurrentStack<string[]> stack = new ConcurrentStack<string[]>();
    static Data()
    {
        List<string[]> strings = new List<string[]>() {
            new string[] { "one" },
            new string[] { "two" },
            new string[] { "three" },
            new string[] { "four" },
            new string[] { "five" },
            new string[] { "six" },
            new string[] { "seven" },
            new string[] { "eight" },
            new string[] { "nine" },
            new string[] { "ten" }
        };
        foreach (var str in strings)
            stack.Push(str);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestData()
    {
        foreach (var str in stack)
            yield return new object[] { str };
    }
}
public abstract class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;
    public UnitTest1(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        _testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestData() => Data.GetTestData();
    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(GetTestData))]
    public void Test1(string arg)
    {
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Start: {arg}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Done");
    }
}
public class TestA : UnitTest1
{
    public TestA(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper) : base(testOutputHelper)
    {
    }
}
public class TestB : UnitTest1
{
    public TestB(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper) : base(testOutputHelper)
    {
    }
}
public class TestC : UnitTest1
{
    public TestC(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper) : base(testOutputHelper)
    {
    }
}
public class TestD : UnitTest1
{
    public TestD(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper) : base(testOutputHelper)
    {
    }
}
```

As it stands, this code runs but executes all 10 tests 4 times each because each test class gets the same data from the iterator.

How can I ensure that each test class instance’s test method receives unique items from the test data source in a parallel environment?

Comment: You could try using a CollectionFixture to provide the test data instead of a static member. See https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context. I used this to share and reuse expensive-to-create objects between various test classes. It wasn't a multithreading test however. XUnit enumerates the static member "offline" before starting any tests, so each of the tests gets the full list. If you use a collection fixture, a single object would be providing all the data on a first-come-first-serve basis. XUnit won't be able to list the individual tests in the Test Explorer, however.

Comment: You won't be able to use the CollectionFixture in a Theory as member data provider, however, each test would have to be a Fact that needs to call up all its data by repeated calls to the fixture within the test itself. All the tests will run, but the Unit Test Taliban would complain about more than one assertion per test.